# Is it possible to retrieve the default MessageBox question icon for usage in my own form?

Tags: c#, winforms

Sounds so trivial that it probably has been asked before, but I can't find it.

I want to ask the user a question that can't be answered yes or no. E.g. button names should be "Fish" or "Meat". To my knowledge this is not possible with the default MessageBox class. So I am creating my own form.

But can I retrieve one of the standard Icons of MessageBox (e.g. the one behind MessageBoxIcon.Question) to make it look more like the default MessageBox?

Comment: I am sorry, you're going to find yourself in a rats-nest of P/Invoke to get this working. The function you want is LoadIcon to get a copy of it, but it will not be in an Icon object so you're going to have to do quite a bit more to make it show up. Personally I'd P/Invoke CreateWindow for a static. But it's far too much work for me to type up whole.

Comment: Thanks Joshua for thinking about it. I have already opted for the lazy way (see my answer below).

Comment: Readily available through a .Net class: [SystemIcons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.systemicons) (e.g., `SystemIcons.Question`).

Comment: @Jimi: worked like a charm! If you post it as a short answer, I'll accept it. Otherwise I'll replace my answer's content.

Comment: Well, since you already have an answer here, you could just add it this information to yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi), I have learned that .NET supports these kinds of icons out of the box. I added this to a panel on my dialog form.

```
this.panel1.BackgroundImage = Bitmap.FromHicon(SystemIcons.Question.Handle);
this.panel1.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Center;
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.systemicons

Comment: How can it be a copyright violation if you aren't copying the resource and including it as your own?

Answer (score -1):

We have a C# class that does it just a reliably as any other thing in Windows. This specific PInvoke code isn't rocket science.

Although I can't give you our source code, I can point you at code which is using all of the same PInvoke calls that we are using.  https://github.com/TsudaKageyu/IconExtractor

It is THIS EASY to use :)

```
myIconExtractor = new IconExtractor(fileName);
myIcon = myIconExtractor.GetIcon(iconIndex);
```

Comment: Why has this answer been down-voted TWICE?  I get it that @Jimi answered the generic question (and well done!) but what on earth could I have done wrong providing an answer that would work for any icon?